# Java - Check if array contains 3 consecutive dates

Tags: java, arrays, date

Hi I have a String[] array that contains dates in the format YYYY/MM/DD. I want to iterate through this array and see if the next 2 elements in the array contain consecutive dates. If they do then just increase the count variable. Here is what I have so far. I just basically need help regarding the if statement that checks if there are 3 consecutive dates.

```
int count = 0;

String[] dates = { 
        "2004/1/23", "2004/1/24", "2004/1/25",
        "2004/1/26", "2004/1/29", "2004/2/11", 
        "2004/2/17", "2004/2/18", "2004/2/18", "2004/3/7"};

for(int i = 0; i < dates.length-2; i++){

    //Help needed here! If i, i+1 and i+2 are consecutive...
    if(...){
        count++;
    }
}
```

I realise that I might need to convert the String dates into an actual Date object before I can compare them. Further guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes converting them to `Date` can actually save you lots of time and work.

Comment: Why don't you keep the dates in a `Dates[]`?What's the point to convert back and forth?

Comment: @Cratylus - Because I need to use their String representation for another method

Comment: @Matt9Atkins then why not just convert the date to a string representation when you need it?

Comment: @I82Much - Its not just that, they are also in string format because they were read directly from a text file

Comment: @Matt9Atkins:So what?If your core algorithm manipulates `Date` then convert them to `Date` as you read-in the text file and just use `toString()` or any string conversion only when you need a string.Don't complicate things when you don't have to

Comment: Did you mean to repeat Feb 18 twice? Is should that the 18th and the 19th?

Comment: There are more interesting answers with [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372209/how-to-check-array-of-dates-are-consecutive-from-todays-date).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert `String[]` to `Date[]` (i.e., prepare a `Date` array). I presume you already know how to do this.

Now you can check for consecutive dates with something like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int numConsecutive = 0;
Date last = null;

for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    c.setTime(dates[i]);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    if (c.getTime().equals(last)) {
        numConsecutive++;
    } else {
        numConsecutive = 0;
    }
    if (numConsecutive == 2) {
        numConsecutive = 0;
        count++;
    }
    last = dates[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use `java.time.LocalDate` class.

```
if ( z.minusDays ( 1 ).isEqual ( y ) && z.minusDays ( 2 ).isEqual ( x ) )  …
```

## Using java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes rather than the troublesome old legacy classes `Date` & `Calendar`.

First convert your array to a list of `LocalDate` objects. I changed your example data as I assume you meant the 18th and 19th of February rather than repeating the 18th twice.

```
String[] dates = {
        "2004/1/23" , "2004/1/24" , "2004/1/25" ,
        "2004/1/26" , "2004/1/29" , "2004/2/11" ,
        "2004/2/17" , "2004/2/18" , "2004/2/19" , "2004/3/7" };

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuu/M/d" );
List < LocalDate > localdates = new ArrayList <> ( dates.length );
for ( String input : dates ) {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse ( input, f );
    localdates.add ( ld );
}
```

Loop the `LocalDate` list, remembering the previous two items. If the current and the previous two are all sequential dates, then increment your counter.

```
Integer tripletCount = 0;
List< LocalDate > tripletDates = new ArrayList<>();
LocalDate x = null;
LocalDate y = null;
for ( LocalDate z : localdates ) {
    if ( null == x ) { x = z; continue; }
    if ( null == y ) { y = z; continue; }
    if ( z.minusDays ( 1 ).isEqual ( y ) && z.minusDays ( 2 ).isEqual ( x ) ) {
        tripletCount= ( tripletCount + 1 );
        tripletDates.add( z );
    }
    // Prepare for next loop.
    x = y ;
    y = z ;
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "localdates: " + localdates );
System.out.println ( "tripletCount: " + tripletCount );
System.out.println ( "tripletDates: " + tripletDates );
```

> localdates: [2004-01-23, 2004-01-24, 2004-01-25, 2004-01-26, 2004-01-29, 2004-02-11, 2004-02-17, 2004-02-18, 2004-02-19, 2004-03-07]
>
> tripletCount: 3
>
> tripletDates: [2004-01-25, 2004-01-26, 2004-02-19]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you will need to calculate the amount of seconds between two dates and then tranform into number of days:

```
import java.util.*;  
class DateDiff  
{  
    public static void main(String [] args)  
    {  
        Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();  
        c1.set(2011,5, 29 );  
        Calendar c2=Calendar.getInstance();  
        c2.set(2012,5,30);  

        Date d1=c1.getTime();  
        Date d2=c2.getTime();  

        long diff=d2.getTime()-d1.getTime();  
        int noofdays=(int)(diff/(1000*24*60*60));  
        System.out.println(noofdays);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Or you could just see if after [adding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)) one day to `c1` you get `c2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void threeConsecutiveDates() throws ParseException {
    List<Date> consecutive = new ArrayList<>();
    consecutive.add(new Date(0));
    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    String[] dates = {
            "2004/1/23", "2004/1/24", "2004/1/25",
            "2004/1/26", "2004/1/29", "2004/2/11",
            "2004/2/17", "2004/2/18", "2004/2/18", "2004/3/7"};
    for (String s : dates) {
        Date previous = consecutive.get(consecutive.size()-1);
        Date current = format.parse(s);
        if(previous.before(current) && (current.getTime()-previous.getTime() == 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) {
            consecutive.add(current);
        } else {
            consecutive.clear();
            consecutive.add(current);
        }
        if(consecutive.size() == 3) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("consecutive = " + consecutive);
}
```