# Print consecutive dates using hyphen

Tags: java, android, xml, date, time

I have a list of dates in the form of ddMMMyyyy stored in one single string. The dates may or may not be consecutive
I print those dates as individual dates. I want to remove that and use hyphen if the dates are consecutive.

**For Example**

```
13Aug2020
15Aug2020 - 18Aug2020
22Aug2020
```

**Instead of**

```
13Aug2020
15Aug2020
16Aug2020
17Aug2020
18Aug2020
22Aug2020
```

Code used to Print Dates :

```
mDateView.setText(mDateValue.replace(",", "\n"));
```

where **mDateView** is a Textview and **mDateValue** is the String containing all the dates seperated by Commas

Comment: Where exactly does XML come into it?

Comment: Try converting the date strings into Date objects and then work with looping to find out the last date of the series. see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15211132/5454852

Comment: Looks like a simple programming task, where exactly did you struggle?

Comment: By the way, the [standard way to represent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) an interval of time textually is with a slash character separating your dates, rather than spaces and a hyphen. `2020-08-15/2020-08-18`

Answer (score 2):

Parse each string into a `LocalDate` object using a `DateTimeFormatter`. Search for how (if your search leads to a page using the old and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`, avoid that). Create two variables for the start and end of the current interval. Store the first date into *both*. In a loop over the remaining dates:

- If the current date is one day after the end, store it into the end, thus extending the interval by one day.
- Otherwise print the current interval, see below for how. Then again store the current date into both start and end.

After the loop terminates, print the current interval.

How to print the current interval: if start and end are equal, print only one of them; otherwise print both with an en-dash between them. In either case format each printed date into the desired format, for example the original format using the same `DateTimeFormatter`.

To determine whether current date is one day after end, use the `plusDays` and the `isEqual` methods of `LocalDate`.

### Question: Doesn’t `LocalDate` require Android API level 26?

`LocalDate` is part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API. java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Documentation of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter)
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.